# To have the value stored / stay after going to another form

Tags: c#

How to keep the value in textbox after changing to another form , So that all  users go in will see the same value / data typed in textbox by another user

```
                txtID1.Text = txtUsername.Text;
                txtName1.Text = ItemName.Text;
                txtDescription1.Text = ItemDescription.Text;
                txtPrice1.Text = ItemPrice.Text;
                ItemName.Text = "";
                ItemDescription.Text = "";
                ItemPrice.Text = "";
              //  }
```

Comment: You really need to read [ask]. What you've asked doesn't make sense because if you're on a form, with some text in a textbox, and you open a new form and then come back to this one then the text will still be there. You're doing something different so you haven't explained this too well.

Comment: My bad ,Haitham Shaddad got it  , My meaning is to maintain the value in textbox even if the user left the form and navigated to another page then back to the old page , as long as c# keeps running

Comment: as you might be on winform, for quick solution declare a static variable

Comment: Is this WinForms, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, WPF, something else?

Comment: @brykneval static variable will make the field has the same value for all users accessing the site

Comment: Yes i'm in winform , What do u mean by declare a static variable?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include sample code, this code should exist in the aspx page or in a separate JavaScript file and reference it in your aspx

Comment: @Haitham Shaddad What if it's brykeval method by using static variable? to make the field the same value for all users accessing the site

Comment: Do you want the field value to be the same for all users or it should be maintained for each user alone?
The method I explained will not require going back to the server as it is totally client side, the static variable method will require the page to post back to the server to save the value in a static variable and this variable will get overridden by other users and the last user wins

Comment: Maintain same value for all same users @Haitham Shaddad

Comment: I can't understand why do you want to do that but why not to hardcode the value in Text property in the aspx ? can you give us a hint about what your business need is?

Comment: It isnt business more on a school online shopping project , Which user will input data in textbox and it will bring over to another textbox , When you go into another form , the " input data " will still stay there @Hitham Shaddad

Comment: @brykeneval How do u do regarding the static variable?

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah @swe i already changed the description regarding what i'm asking

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the value in a text box even if the user left the form and navigated to another page then back to the old page, then you can do that using cookie, add an event handler on keydown or blur to the textbox and inside the event, create a cookie if it doesn't exist then update its value with the text inside the text box.

On the page load, check if the cookie exist and if so, read the value and set the value of the text box.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#textboxId").blur(function() {
      setCookie('textboxVaue',$("#textboxId").val(),1);
    });

var existingCookieValue = getCookie('textboxVaue');
if(existingCookieValue)
  $("#textboxId").val(existingCookieValue);
});

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I got get about the cookies , Is there any a video or an example regarding what i'm asking? As i couldnt find it

Comment: I don't understand your comment, do you need something to show you how to read and write cookies or what?

Comment: Yes , It's winform , What i mean was to maintain the value in textbox after you've typed and changing forms and it still stays there

Comment: @brykneval it doesn't matter, the solution is totally JavaScript

Comment: @HaithamShaddad how is it javascript and how do you set cookie in winform?